# Programmatic Destructuring

Tags: javascript

I have a different use case in which when using the concept of destructuring I want the name of new variable to come from different variables.

For ex (usual destructuring):

```js
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p: foo, q: bar} = o;
console.log(foo, bar); // Works fine
```

Is working fine but when I try to replace `p, foo, q, bar` with some other variable I get the error because I can not get the syntax right.

The closest I have reached is:

```js
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var x1 = "p";
var x2 = "foo";
var x3 = "q";
var x4 = "bar";
var {[x1]: foo, [x3]: bar} = o;
console.log(foo, bar);
```

Othe things which I tried but didnt work are:

```
var {[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: bar} = o; //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
var {[x1]: (()=>x2)(), q: bar} = o; //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

But here I am still not able to replace `foo, bar` with `x2, x4`.

Any idea how can one achieve this? Or is it even possible to do this?

Comment: "I am still not able to replace foo, bar with x2, x4."...the code sample doesn't demonstrate precisely what you tried to do or what error you got. Also can you give us a clearer explanation of what you're trying to achieve and why?

Comment: @ADyson okay check the updated question if the failed attempts helps you in any way. What I am trying to achieve is I guess clearly mentioned in the question itself. And why shouldn't I be curious about this concept? Thanks for the time :)

Comment: I never said you shouldn't be curious? Just wondered if you had a practical use case, that's all. You still didn't mention the resulting error message. "Not able to" doesn't really mean anything. Can you make that last bit into a snippet like the others?

Comment: The issue is you need an lvalue to assign to. Instead of `var {[x1]: foo, [x3]: bar} = o;` try `({[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o);`. It's similar to trying to write `let [dynamic string] = value;`, you can't generate the variable name you want to declare dynamically from what i know.

Comment: @ADyson mentioned the error there.

Comment: I don't get it why people downvote the question when they don't have/want to share an opinion on it?

Comment: @ASDFGerte that works! Why dont you post it as an answer. :)

Comment: yes as @ASDFGerte says use ({[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o) or eval({[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o)

Comment: @ABUdhay yea...

Answer (score 2):

You need an lvalue to assign to, but from what i know, you cannot declare dynamically generated variable names, as in `let [dynamicName] = value`. However, object properties are an alternative, which can dynamically be generated:

```js
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var container = {};
var x1 = "p";
var x2 = "foo";
var x3 = "q";
var x4 = "bar";
({[x1]: container[x2], [x3]: container[x4]} = o);
console.log(container.foo, container.bar);
```

On global scope, you can abuse the fact that the global object is being used as object environment, and use `window[x2]` and `window[x4]`, but it's not really useful in production code.

Answer (score 1):

It was answered perfectly [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399729/programmatic-destructuring#comment89770482_51399729). I'll try to explain with the specification details.

When we declare a variable, like this

```
var {[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o;
```

*I removed all the subscripted text from the spec for brevity*

it would follow the following production as per [Variable Statement Section](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-variable-statement),

```
VariableStatement:
    var VariableDeclarationList;

VariableDeclarationList:
    VariableDeclaration
    VariableDeclarationList, VariableDeclaration

VariableDeclaration:
    BindingIdentifier Initializer
    BindingPattern Initializer
```

As `{[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]}` is not a [`BindingIdentifier`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-BindingIdentifier), it is a [`BindingPattern`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-BindingPattern). And that production goes like this

```
BindingPattern:
    ObjectBindingPattern
    ArrayBindingPattern

ObjectBindingPattern:
    {}
    {BindingRestProperty}
    {BindingPropertyList}
    {BindingPropertyList, BindingRestProperty}

...
...

BindingPropertyList:
    BindingProperty
    BindingPropertyList, BindingProperty

...
...

BindingProperty:
    SingleNameBinding
    PropertyName: BindingElement

BindingElement:
    SingleNameBinding
    BindingPattern Initializer

SingleNameBinding:
    BindingIdentifier Initializer
```

In this case (`{[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]}`), the production goes like this `BindingPattern` -> `ObjectBindingPattern` -> `{BindingPropertyList}` -> `BindingProperty` -> `PropertyName: BindingElement` -> `SingleNameBinding` -> `BindingIdentifier`.

At this point, `window[x2]` is not a `BindingIdentifier`. That is why you are getting the `SyntaxError`, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`.

---

But it works in case of `({[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o)` because, it is not a variable declaration anymore. It is a [destructuring assignment](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-destructuring-assignment).

Production for that goes like this

```
AssignmentPattern:
    ObjectAssignmentPattern
    ArrayAssignmentPattern

ObjectAssignmentPattern:
    {}
    {AssignmentRestProperty}
    {AssignmentPropertyList}
    {AssignmentPropertyList, AssignmentRestProperty}

AssignmentPropertyList:
    AssignmentProperty
    AssignmentPropertyList, AssignmentProperty

AssignmentProperty:
    IdentifierReference Initializer
    PropertyName: AssignmentElement

AssignmentElement:
    DestructuringAssignmentTarget Initializer

DestructuringAssignmentTarget:
    LeftHandSideExpression

LeftHandSideExpression:
    NewExpression
    CallExpression

CallExpression:
    CoverCallExpressionAndAsyncArrowHead
    SuperCall
    CallExpression Arguments
    CallExpression[Expression]
    CallExpression.IdentifierName
    CallExpression TemplateLiteral
```

Here the production is complete with `CallExpression[Expression]`. That is why `({[x1]: window[x2], [x3]: window[x4]} = o)` is valid and it is working.